# How to upload text view from android to a database in a website using a button

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm currently doing a project from one of my subjects in my university. I'm about to do an attendance app that checks if the professors are present, late, or absent in the room based on the schedule. I made an app in an android studio which uses radio groups and radio buttons that will change the text in the text view which will show if the professors attendance status. I'm thinking of making a button that will upload the text views with the attendance statuses to a website which holds the data(database).

I'm not used to programming in the android studio that is why I would like to know if a way to upload the text views on a website. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, You have to create Weg api that you can call from the android mobile application and pass the current status of the professor or the whatever you want to pass on the server. That api will update the database as per whatever you have passed from the mobile application.

Also, One more thing that you can not pass the text view, you just need to pass the text of that view.

I hope, you will get answer from this.

Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

Assign value of textview to a string variable.
And use this string in your api to pass data.

For example if you have a textview with name `teacher`, you can get its value using this line.

```
String st_teacher = teacher.getText();
```

Now use that `st_teacher` value in your api to upload data.